# EXCEL VBA Type Mismatch Error "13" Assigning Date Data Type to Variable

Tags: vba, date, excel

I'm trying to loop through a column of dates, and any date that is within two other set dates (First Day of Week, Last Day of Week) or (First Day of Month, Last Day of Month).

When I go to assign the date in the column to a variable, I get a type mismatch error.

```
Sub JobsDue(ByRef DateStart As Date, ByRef DateEnd As Date)
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim JobDueDate As String
Dim JobPN As String
For i = 10 To LastRow
JobDueDate = Sheet1.Range("B" & 10, "B" & i).Value (ERROR OCCURS HERE)
JobPN = Sheet1.Range("C" & 10, "C" & i).Value


If (JobDueDate) >= DateStart And (JobDueDate) <= DateEnd Then
lbJobsDue.AddItem (JobPN & "," & CDate(JobDueDate))
End If

Next i
End Sub


Private Sub comboxJobsDue_Change()

If comboxJobsDue.Value = "This Week" Then

StartOfWeek = Date - Weekday(Date) + 2

endofweek = Date - Weekday(Date) + 6
lblJobsDue.Caption = (StartOfWeek) & "-" & (endofweek)

Call JobsDue((StartOfWeek), (endofweek))

ElseIf comboxJobsDue.Value = "Next Week" Then
StartOfWeek = Date - Weekday(Date) + 9
endofweek = Date - Weekday(Date) + 13
lblJobsDue.Caption = (StartOfWeek) & "-" & (endofweek)

ElseIf comboxJobsDue.Value = "This Month" Then
FirstDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
LastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
lblJobsDue.Caption = FirstDayInMonth & "-" & LastDayInMonth

ElseIf comboxJobsDue.Value = "Next Month" Then
FirstDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1)
LastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 2, 0)
lblJobsDue.Caption = FirstDayInMonth & "-" & LastDayInMonth
End If
End Sub
```

The error occurs on Line 7, when I run the program to debug, JobDueDate gets a date but it is in the format of "9/25/2013", the other dates are of the format 8/18/2014 WITHOUT quotation marks. Can anyone explain to me why this error is happening and how I can go about fixing it?

Thanks in advance, Evan

Comment: see the line declaration reading "`Dim JobDueDate As String`" (line 4 I think)  you're telling the system you want it as a string...  Perhaps you want `Dim JobDueDate As Date` so you can use date functions on it.  DateStart and End are being passed in as dates so they would error on the code calling this sub if they passed in invalid dates. Additionally, you appear to be attempting to assign a range of dates to a date field.  You either need a collection of dates or an array of dates to handle this.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I was trying to assign the range of dates to the variable instead of one cell at a time. I changed it to .Cells(i,2) and it worked like a charm. I also had the As Date changed to As String in my desperate attempts to fix my problem, I just forgot to change it back before I posted it on here. Thank you so much though.

Comment: Ehh, which is line 7?

Comment: The one that reads `JobDueDate = Sheet1.Range("B" & 10, "B" & i).Value (ERROR OCCURS HERE)` note the `(ERROR OCCURS HERE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the line declaration reading `"Dim JobDueDate As String"` (line 4 I think) You're telling the system you want it as a string... Perhaps you want `Dim JobDueDate As Date` so you can use date functions on it.

DateStart and End are being passed in as dates so they would error on the code calling this sub if they passed in invalid dates.

Additionally, you appear to be attempting to assign a range of dates to a date field. You either need a collection of dates or an array of dates to handle this.